# csproj equivalent to nuspec target attribute

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

NuGet nuspec files allow you to specify the [`target` for `<file>` elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001655#using-the-files-element-for-content-files).

eg.

```xml
<files>
  <file src="things/**/*" target="content/stuff/" />
</files>
```

Is there an equivalent if you're using a csproj (and `dotnet pack`), instead of a .nuspec file?

eg. Given

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="things/**/*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Can I add something to that to make those files end up in `content/stuff` in the .nupkg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package), I'd say it should look like this:

```xml
<Content Include="things/**/*">
  <Pack>true</Pack>
  <PackagePath>content/stuff/</PackagePath>
</Content>
```